# Height of Mirror Required

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection

I was curious about the minimum height of a mirror required to see your full body, and I found out that it was half of your height, in other words the minimum height to view the image = your height / 2. Using this, how do you calculate the minimum height of a mirror required to view *other* objects. For instance, say you have an object half of the distance to the mirror that you are (if you are 1 meter away, the object will be at 0.5). Is there a relationship to find out what height the mirror must be to see the whole object, in terms of the height of the object? Assume the mirror is a plane mirror.

Edit: Making it clearer, I'll include a practice question. You are standing near a plane mirror at a distance of 2d, and there is a ball at point d. What height must the mirror be, in terms of height of the ball, b, in order for you to observe the whole ball in the mirror?

Edit 2: My specific question is how do you find the minimum height of the mirror required to see objects *other* than you in the mirror. For example, say you are standing near a plane mirror with a distance of 2d, and there is a cat at distance d from plane mirror. What height must the mirror be, in terms of height of the cat, h in order for you to observe the whole ball in the mirror?

Comment: Assume the mirror is a plane mirror, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to understand it better if you imagine that the mirror forms a reflection of every object present in front of its reflecting surface.

It will only be visible to you when your field of view makes it possible to see the reflection.

[image: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Plane_mirror.png#/media/File:Plane_mirror.png]

In this diagram, object A forms a reflection A'. It is only when the field of view of the person covers the reflection for it to be visible.

Note that if the mirror were to be smaller and not lie beneath A, even then a reflection would be formed whose view would be limited by the light rays reaching you after reflecting at a certain angle.

Answer (score 0):

To see your whole body the top of that mirror must be aligned with the top of your head. The reason you need a mirror half your height is because a ray from your eye to the bottom of the mirror hits your feet. This does not depend on how far away you are from the mirror. The ray to the top of the mirror just bounces straight back to your eyes. Rays hitting in between reach some other place on your body.

To find the maximal view for a given mirror, draw one ray from your eye to each of the edges, and let it reflect off by the law of reflection. The range encompassed by those two rays is what will be visible.